# Is OR function in Excel validations broken?

Tags: excel, logical-or

I'm trying to write a custom validation function in Excel that assures that the text in a cell starts with `http://` or `https://`. If I use the formula

> =EXACT(LEFT(INDIRECT("Z"&ROW()), 8), "https://")

the validation works but only checks for https://. If I add an OR like this

> =OR(EXACT(LEFT(INDIRECT("Z"&ROW()), 8), "https://"), EXACT(LEFT(INDIRECT("Z"&ROW()), 7), "http://"))

it does not work; it always evaluates to false. I then tried the following just to test the OR function:

> =OR(EXACT(LEFT(INDIRECT("Z"&ROW()), 8), "https://"), TRUE)

and this also evaluates to FALSE! Am I crazy or is the OR function broken? I found that when pasting this equation in a cell it works just fine. It only doesn't work when it's used as a custom validation function.

Comment: Not the problem but why the unecessary use of a voltile INDIRECT when a simple putting `Z3` or what ever row number is the first row of the validation?

Comment: Excel 2016 gives "The formula currently evaluates to an error, do you wish to continue?" on that one. Removing `INDIRECT` like @ScottCraner said fixes it (both the error message and the formula logic).

Comment: @ScottCraner I used the INDIRECT() and ROW() because I was hoping to select the entire column and then apply this validation to it.

Comment: Then use `$Z1` instead.  As long as it refers to the upper left cell Excel will make the relative part iterate correctly, without the need of 1.04 million volatile formulas.

Comment: That worked. Still not sure why my original attempt didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If one day you need to include a third condition, try like this:

```
=OR(LEFT(D1,8)="https://",
    LEFT(D1,7)="http://")
```

It will work without `Exact()`.
As noted in the comments, `If()` is also not needed.

Comment: Why not just `=OR(
(LEFT(D1,8)="https://",1),
(LEFT(D1,7)="http://",1))` as both expressions already are boolean?

Comment: I like putting new lines in the formulas, looks better to me. @user1016274

Comment: I meant: you don't need the `IF()` function because the expression itself already is a boolean value. Not about the newlines.

Comment: @user1016274 - I got your point, thus it is a bit better indeed, you have to remove the `1` from the formula and it works. Hence, I have edited the answer.